# parsing data from json string

Tags: javascript, php, json

Previous similar questions on SO gave me clue but due to json format in my case, I have issue.
I parse the content of $url using `file_get_content($url)`.

Which gives me result json string:

```
{
   "http://ec.x.x.x.xcompute-1.amazonaws.com/": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [
            {
               "id": "239_320054",
               "from": {
                  "name": "x",
                  "id": "46353"
               },
               "message": "testing",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-10-02T10:47:30+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            },
            {
               "id": "181319910",
               "from": {
                  "name": "y",
                  "id": "166353"
               },
               "message": "hi",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-10-02T07:30:00+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            }
         ],
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "after": "MQ==",
               "before": "Mg=="
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My question: How to parse all messages in single string from above json string?

from the clue I got from other SO answer and reference, I could do:

```
$json = "above_json_result";
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'message'};
```

Here is my entire code which does not give any result:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function show() {

    alert("hi");

 var json = '{
   "http://x.x.x.x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [
            {
               "id": "f434343",
               "from": {
                  "name": "x",
                  "id": "1666353"
               },
               "message": "testing",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-10-02T10:47:30+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            },
            {
               "id": "181596_319910",
               "from": {
                  "name": "y",
                  "id": "10546353"
               },
               "message": "hi",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-10-02T07:30:00+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            }
         ],
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "after": "MQ==",
               "before": "Mg=="
            }
         }
      }
   }
}';

var obj = json_decode($json);
    alert(obj->{'message'});


}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="show()">
<button type="submit" value="click " onclick="show()"> button </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: `alert`? `<script>`? In PHP? Seems you're confusing JavaScript with PHP.

Comment: You trying to execute php code incorrectly. See [*php tag wiki*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) for guidance.

Comment: within a function I can `alert()`. I dont think any issue!

Comment: @Programming_crazy: Put within a JavaScript function you cannot use PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write php in javascript but you dind't include php tags

```
function show() {

    alert("hi");
<?php
 $json = '{
   "http://x.x.x.x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [
            {
               "id": "f434343",
               "from": {
                  "name": "x",
                  "id": "1666353"
               },
               "message": "testing",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-10-02T10:47:30+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            },
            {
               "id": "181596_319910",
               "from": {
                  "name": "y",
                  "id": "10546353"
               },
               "message": "hi",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-10-02T07:30:00+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            }
         ],
         "paging": {
            "cursors": {
               "after": "MQ==",
               "before": "Mg=="
            }
         }
      }
   }
}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo "    alert(" . $obj->{'message'} . ");";

?>

}
```

Also your JSON object don't contain message as top level, messages are nested so you need to use:

```
$data = $obj->{'http://x.x.x.x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/'}->comments->data;
foreach ($data as $obj) {
    echo "    alert(" . $obj->message . ");";
}
```

Comment: @Programming_crazy your object don't have message as top level property, try `$obj->{'http://x.x.x.x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/'}->comments->data[0]->message`

Answer (score 1):

This could do it for you. (numbered the levels in the foreach loops)

```
   foreach ($obj as $one) {
        foreach ($one as $two) {
            foreach($two as $three) {
                foreach($three as $four) {
                    print $four->message . '<br />';
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```